# Sending Json Form from Flash AS3

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash, form-post

i am having one form accepting json post in Asp.net which i need to call from Flash As3...

i am using  below code to do that. I have seen some post in which they say its working fine.
But i am encountering below Error

`Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.`

Here is my code.

```
        var messages:Array = new Array ();


        messages.push({"From":fromemailTxt.text,"To": ToemailTxt.text,"Body": BodyText.text,"Subject":SubjectText.text});

        var JsonObj:String = JSON.encode(messages);
        trace(JsonObj);

        var variables:URLVariables=new URLVariables(JsonObj);



        RequestURL= srvStringURL;

        var JSONLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        JSONLoader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

        JSONLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, GetBookmarkURLError, false, 0, true);
        JSONLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseBookmarkURLResult, false, 0, true);


        var hdr:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(RequestURL);
        request.requestHeaders.push(hdr);
        request.data=variables;
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        try 
        {
            JSONLoader.load(request);
        }
        catch (error:ArgumentError) 
        { 
            trace("An ArgumentError has occurred."+error.errorID.toString()); 
        } 
        catch (error:SecurityError) 
        { 
            trace("A SecurityError has occurred."); 
        }
        catch (error:Error) 
        {
            trace("Unable to load requested document.");
        }
```

Anybody have any idea on this??
Thanks

Comment: I know that .Net is different, but the standard for Flex is to camelCase properties. Only classes are ProperCased

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is, because you are passing incorrect string to [URLVariables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html#decode%28%29) constructor. Do not use URLVariables. Instead pass data as string: `request.data=JsonObj;`

Comment: thanks @user1113426, you solved my issue. i got that, we should not use urlVaribales for json form post. i guess same should apply if we use XML form post.

Comment: @meghana Use `URLVariables` only when you are sending {name,value} pairs. In other cases, just use simple text data.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I am using to consume REST Web service and pass json parameter to service it shows. Error #2032: Stream Error.
Andy idea what is going wrong

```
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
ldr.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

var strData:String = "{\"gparam\": [ {\"productid\": \"" + productId + "\"},{\"message\": \"" + mesage + "\"},{\"googleappid\": \"" + googleappid + "\"},{\"senderid\": \"" + senderid + "\"},{\"appname\": \"" + appName + "\"},{\"userid\": \"" + userId + "\"},{\"receiverid\": \"" + receiverId + "\"} ]}";

var hdr:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/AndroidGCM/GCMNotification.svc/SendGCM");
req.requestHeaders.push(hdr);
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
req.data = strData;

trace("data: " + req.data);

ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplete);
ldr.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR , onError);
ldr.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR ,onSecurityErr);

ldr.load(req);

function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    trace("LOAD COMPLETE: " + ldr.data);
TextField(parMC.getChildByName("txtCheck")).appendText("\n LOAD COMPLETE: " + ldr.data);
}
function onSecurityErr(e:SecurityErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("error: " + e.text );
}
function onError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("error: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: I think, you should post this in different question.